# Create a program that calculates how many objects in the list object_list have the same hash value as some other element in the list

Tags: python, hash, hashtable, hashcode

Create a program that calculates how many objects in the list object_list have the same hash value as some other element in the list. The output should be the number of those objects. If there are no matching hash values, the output should be 0.

For example, if object_list = [1, 397, 27468, -95, 1309, 397, -539874, -240767, -95, 397], the output should be 5.

Keep in mind that not every object in the list may be hashable!

```
# the object_list has already been defined
from collections.abc import Hashable
output = 0
# write your code here
for obj in object_list:
    if isinstance(obj, Hashable) == True:
        hash_value = obj
        if hash_value.__eq__(object_list):
            output += 1

print(output)
```

Comment: Why output should be 5?

Comment: [Homework is not on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 0):

You can test if object is hashable if has `__hash__` magic method. To count number of same hash values, you can use `collection.Counter` and `sum()` builtin method.

For example:

```
from collections import Counter

object_list = [1, 397, 27468, -95, 1309, 397, -539874, -240767, -95, 397]

s = sum(v for v in Counter(hash(v) for v in object_list if getattr(v, '__hash__')).values() if v > 1)
print(s)
```

Prints:

```
5
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple list comprehension

```
sum([1  for obj in object_list if isinstance(obj, Hashable) and hash(obj)>1])
```